# RxJS, why does fromEvent() register a new event for each subscription?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Let's say we have following code

```
const clickEvent$ = fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(
    pluck('target')
);

clickEvent$.pipe(
    filter(node => node.id === 'button1')
).subscribe(() => {
    console.log('Button 1 clicked!');
});

clickEvent$.pipe(
    filter(node => node.id === 'button2')
).subscribe(() => {
    console.log('Button 2 clicked!');
});
```

When I look at the registered events in debugger I see that there are two click events registered on the document. When in increase number of subscriptions to `clickEvent$`, the number of events registered to document also increases with each subscription.

[debugger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5lei.png)

In comparison the code below only registers one event no matter how many cases I add to `switch` statement.

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    switch (event.target.id) {
        case 'Button1':
            console.log('Button 1 clicked!');
            break;
        case 'Button2':
            console.log('Button 2 clicked!');
            break;
    }
});
```

So my question is :-

- Why does each subscription to clickEvent$ (or any DOM Event Stream) add a new event to document.
- How does it affect performance when there 100 or more subscriptions
- Is there a way around this to have only one event listener added to documen.

Here's what I know about Hot and Cold observables

- All observable sequences created from DOM events are Hot and shared by default.
- In case of a Hot observable, subscribers only start receiving events from the time of subscription. Whereas in case of a cold observable subscribers receive all events that the observable can produce.
- `share()` operator can be used to make a cold observable hot.

Thanks!

Comment: That's just how it works. You need share or shareReplay. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as you can see by clicking `run code snippet`, **the answer is yes**, listeners are being attached every time you `subscribe` to the `click$` stream.

> > Every time resulting Observable is subscribed, event handler function will be registered to event target on given event type. When that event fires, value passed as a first argument to registered function will be emitted by output Observable. When Observable is unsubscribed, function will be unregistered from event target.

```js
const { fromEvent } = rxjs;
const { mapTo } = rxjs.operators;

const target = document.getElementById('test');
/* ignore, debug */
const $delegate = target.addEventListener;

target.addEventListener = (...args) => {
  console.log('registering listener');
  
  return $delegate.apply(target, args);
};
/* // */

const click$ = fromEvent(target, 'click');

click$.pipe(
    mapTo('stream 1: click'),
).subscribe(console.log);

click$.pipe(
    mapTo('stream 2: click'),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.js"></script>

<button id="test">click here</button>
```

#### you can create `shared` streams to avoid that.

```js
const { fromEvent } = rxjs;
const { mapTo, share } = rxjs.operators;

const target = document.getElementById('test');
/* ignore, debug */
const $delegate = target.addEventListener;

target.addEventListener = (...args) => {
  console.log('registering listener');
  
  return $delegate.apply(target, args);
};
/* // */

const click$ = fromEvent(target, 'click').pipe(
  share(), // <= share operator
);

click$.pipe(
    mapTo('stream 1: click'),
).subscribe(console.log);

click$.pipe(
    mapTo('stream 2: click'),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.js"></script>

<button id="test">click here</button>
```

as you can see in this last example, the log `registering listener` is happening only one time. Further information about [`the share operator`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/share)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, using share() operator does solve the problem, but aren't observable created using fromEvent() hot by default, if yes, then why do we need to share an already hot observable.

Comment: `share` creates `multicast observables`, which are hot, but their peculiarity is being multicast. `fromEvent` creates `hot` observables in a sense that data is uncontrolled, and those are not multicast.